# Show that $M=\{p\in P_3: p(5)=0\}$ is a subspace of $P_3$ and find the base and dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that $M=\{p\in P_3: p(5)=0\}$ is a subspace of $P_3$ and find the base and dimension.

So I managed to show that it is a subspace of $P_3$: Let $p,q \in M$.

$(\alpha p+\beta q)(5)=\alpha p(5)+\beta q(5)=\alpha \times 0 +\beta \times 0=0 \Rightarrow \alpha p+\beta q \in M$.

How do I find the base and dimension?

Comment: How many restrictions you see in subspace $M$?

Comment: What do you mean restrictions?

Comment: The conditions to construct subspace $M$. They, actually restrict the dimensions.

Comment: There are 2 conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3\in M\subset P_3$.

$p(5)=0\implies a=-5b-25c-125d$. This reduces $p(x)=-(5b+25c+125d)+bx+cx^2+dx^3$. Now you have to make choices for $b,c$ and $d$ only. So, $dim(M)=3$.